# Implementing array like structure in MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm currently trying to implement a table within my SQL database. I'm looking to create a table that can be used to check if a user on my website has liked a post. The idea is to have a table with one axes iterating the posts on the website and one axis with the userID values iterated. Then in each box hold a binary value as to whether they have liked it. I'm just wondering how I would implement this. I have been doing this in C# by creating classes and converting these into server side code using Entity Framework 6.4.0. 
Any help would be great.

Comment: Sound like you need a many-to-many relationship table in the database

Comment: Sounds like you need to start by doing a quick Database Design Tutorial. There are 1000's out there in the ether PS, dont do it that way you have currently concieved

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting is a normalized structure for your use case; it would, for example, require adding more columns to the table everytime a post is added to the database (or a user, depending on whether you use rows or columns).

A typical database solution would be a bridge table, that represents the many to many relationship between posts and users.

Say table `user_like_posts`, with the following columns:

```
user_id -- foreign key to the "users" table
post_id -- foreign key to the "posts" table
```

You may want to add additional columns to the bridge table, like the timestamp when the user liked the post, or the-like.

Answer (score 0):

Will every user have an opinion on every post? If not then you don't have the data you described. If users and posts are not related one to one then you have a simple relation. For each post that a user likes (or dislikes?) there is an entry for that user:

Likes/Dislikes Table:
    User identifier
    Post identifier
    The binary value that indicates like or dislike

If the table only indicates 'likes' then you don't need the last column.

A design like this would work even if every user and every post is in this table. The table might get large in a hurry and keep growing every time you introduced a new post. But if this table only includes actual 'likes' (and/or 'dislikes') it should be manageable.

For a class you just have an enumerable that has the posts 'liked' (and possibly another that indicates the posts 'disliked.')

Think about what you are trying to represent. Ask yourself questions. Don't just latch on to an idea and try to 'do' it.

Will every user have an opinion of every post?
Do you need to store both 'likes' and 'dislikes?'
Can there be a 'neutral' opinion on a post?
Can users change their opinions?

You can only discover the correct data structure by asking and answering all the questions that matter to your situation (my list is not exhaustive - it is only an example.)